# Connection string with reference to local .mdf on other project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For a school project I got a solution with an ASP.NET MVC application, a `DAL.dll` to access the database and a test class to check my SQL queries.

I created a local database and put it into the `App_Data` folder of my ASP.NET MVC project.

dll class:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValaisBookingDBAccess"].ConnectionString;
```

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ValaisBookingDBAccess"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Pierre\Gdrive\04 Formation\Hevs_60X_3 - Cours\S3\623-11 Implémentation du sytème\Projet\ValaisBooking\ValaisBooking\App_Data\ValaisBooking.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there a way to have a relative path when the `.mdf` file is located in the same solution but other project so I could test my queries with my test class as the ASP.NET MVC project isn't started yet?

Comment: Did you try something? What is your best not working attempt?

Comment: I tried to connect directly in local with Windows Authentication without success.

Comment: Does the Configuration, that you added, work?

Comment: Yes it works without problem

Comment: What is the problem with your tests?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: No. Didn't fond a way to do what I wanted with a relative path

Comment: Can you provide the absolute path of your test-project? Then I could give it a try.

Comment: No response anymore?